# How to send a message in on_message function?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "{")
@bot.event  
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content
    if "hi" in message.content:
        await message.channel.purge( limit = 1 )
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, msg) #The problem is here
    print(f"{message.content}, {message.author}")
```

It says that "Bot" object has no attribute "send_message".
How do I send a message if it contains a word "hi"?

Answer (score 2):

`send_message` is the old discord.py method. In discord.py rewrite (> v1.0) you have to use the [`discord.TextChannel.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=send#discord.TextChannel.send) method in `on_message` events:

```
@bot.event  
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content
    if "hi" in message.content:
        await message.channel.purge(limit = 1)
        await message.channel.send(msg)
```

Here's a [summary between discord.py and discord.py rewrite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html?highlight=migration), in case you don't really what's the difference between the two versions.